# Elasticsearch terms query size to include some terms

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

Elasticsearch docs shows below example for size and includes

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "JapaneseCars": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "make",
        "size": 10
        "include": [ "mazda", "honda" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But here "include" only includes "mazda" and "honda" in results, i want result to include those 2 as well other results based on doc_count since i am using size in query, is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`terms` aggregation always return buckets with highest number of documents.

You cannot define an aggregation to always include buckets for some specified keys AND other top buckets.

But you could define two separate aggregations and merge buckets in your application

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "JapaneseCars": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "make",
        "include": [ "mazda", "honda" ]
      }
    },
    "OtherCars": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "make",
        "exclude": [ "mazda", "honda" ]
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the `include` keyword right:

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "JapaneseCars": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "make",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah but in that case it does not include if size is 10 and that result is not in top 10 based on doc_count